# Ember google map event handling function cannot get `this`

Tags: javascript, ember.js

in my controller
i have following action:

```
actions: {
changeCenter: function(event) {
  this.set('mapLat', event.latlng.lat());
  this.set('mapLng', event.latlng.lng());
}}
```

in my template i am using it as

```
{{g-maps 
name="my-map" 
lat=mapLat lng=mapLng zoom=zoom
circles=circles
showMapTypeControl=false
showScaleControl=false
click=actions.changeCenter}}
```

but when the function is trigger, the `this` keyword is `undefined`. Could some one give me some hint here? 
thanks.

Comment: change `}}` to `}.bind(this)}` may work - not enough code for me to be certain

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe `bind(actions)` for this example

Comment: true dat @AndrewLi - though, isn't actions just a property of some object? but `.bind(this)` is definitely wrong :p - one question is, what does the OP **want** `this` to be! it can be anything he wants using bind

Comment: @JaromandaX i could like `this` to the the ember controller, since i am setting two properties on this controller.

Comment: then bind to the ember controller

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry dont really understand how to bind to ember controller. can you give a code sample? thanks

Comment: neither do I, so sorry

Comment: try `click='changeCenter'`, but I am not sure you will receive `event` but definitely `this` context will be `controller`.

Answer (score 2):

Use it as closure action such as `(action 'actionName')`:

```
{{g-maps 
  name="my-map" 
  lat=mapLat lng=mapLng zoom=zoom
  circles=circles
  showMapTypeControl=false
  showScaleControl=false
  click=(action 'changeCenter')}}
```